# Comparing Azure Machine Disk Performance Targets

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I'm tasked with converting an existing Azure machine and resize it to something with more capacity.

What is the difference between machine storage performance where one machine says 8x500 IOPS and another machine has a value like 12000 IOPS with no multiplier?

For example D12_V2 says 8x500 IOPS and an F4S says 12800 FPS.  How do I compare those?  I plan on having the system drive, a temp drive and 4-5 individual drives.

Comment: Can you post the links where you are seeing those stats? That will help clarify things.  The 8x500 IOPS is 8 disks x 500 IOPS per disk (disk striping for more throughput).  This link may help: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-premium-storage-performance/  I couldn't find a 12000 or 12800 FPS but if you provide the link I should be able to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, Jason.  I am seeing this in the portal when attemping to resize my existing machine.  

`    +---------------------+
    | F4S Standard     |
    | 4   Cores            |
    | 8   GB                 |
    | 12800 Max IOPS|
    | Load Balancing  |
    | Auto Scale          |
    | Premium Disk     |
    +---------------------+`

Comment: Now that you have me hunting a little differently I found this link (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/) which shows both at 12800 IOPS.  So, perhaps just many different viewpoints on the IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft is changing their displaying of IOPS, instead of posting the IOPS per disk, they show the maximum achievable with all disks attached.

```
The F4S:    8 possible data disks with 1600 IOPS each = 12800 IOPS
The D12_V2: 8 possible data disks with  500 IOPS each =  4000 IOPS
```

Like Bruno mentioned the difference between the 500 and 1600 IOPS is in the Premium disks

Answer (score 3):

The difference lies in the storage used by these VMs. "D" (or A or F or G) sized Virtual Machines use Standard Storage. This type of Storage support disks from 1GB to 1023GB with 500IOPS of performance.

[Sizes for virtual machines in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/)

Virtual Machines with an "S" suffix means it can use Premium Storage. So you have DS, FS or even GS size VMs in particular regions. Premium Storage runs SSDs and you may create disks in 3 sizes: 128GB (500IOPS), 512GB (2300IOPS), 1TB (5000IOPS). Premium storage also has higher throughput and considerable lower latency which is great for workloads like databases.

[Premium Storage: High-Performance Storage for Azure Virtual Machine Workloads](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-premium-storage/)

No matter the storage type, for each core, you may have up to 2 disks. A D12 or DS12 VM has 4 CPU cores, that means you may have up to 8 disks: 8x500IOPS (4000) in Standard Storage or 8x5000IOPS (40000) in Premium Storage, both using raid0.

Said that, for you particular scenario, probably you don't need premium storage. It will cost a lot more and won't give you any real benefit. If you need **temporary** and fast i/o, you can use the D:\ temp volume of D-sized Virtual Machines as they use SSD and can reach up to 48000IOPS (D14) and you won't even pay for it. For the other volumes just use standard disks in a striped set (raid0).

[New D-Series Virtual Machine Sizes](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/new-d-series-virtual-machine-sizes/)

[D-Series Performance Expectations](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/d-series-performance-expectations/)